# Do I need to fix this Avocado debarking?

Tags: avocado, damage

This self seeded avocado tree has been growing happily on the slope down from the path at the back of my house. It doesn't get much Sun but it seems to be growing over the last few years with no help from me.

I've noticed this loss of about 60% of the bark on the main stem. So I presume the branches below this area are feeding the roots.

What action should I take?

[image: bark damage]

[image: avocado sapling]